# how to access converted leads

Tags: leads, lead-conversion

Hi i have a custom button which will do lead conversion. After clicking on that , lead gets converted. But as a test user , i am not able to see the converted lead. But i can see as system administrator. I have tried by checking "Enable "Set Audit Fields upon Record Creation" and "Update Records with Inactive Owners" User Permissions" in the User Interface. Also i have checked this check box in both permission set and profile level. Still i am not able to access the lead( even in read only mode).

Comment: I expect this is to do with permissions. I imagine the easiest "fix" would be to allow "View All Data" as a minimum for the Test User's Profile on the Lead object. However, doing this opens it up to everyone using that Profile. You'd want to have a big think about security.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the "View and Edit Converted Leads" permission? A user with that permission can view the actual record of a converted lead. Without the permission when you click on a converted lead you will automatically be navigated to the contact or account.

**Info from Help Article**
Assign the "View and Edit Converted Leads" permission to let marketing and sales operations users view converted leads. Users can also edit converted leads.

**Link to Help article**
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=leads_view_edit_converted.htm&type=5

Answer (score 1):

Once the Leads are converted in a Salesforce Organization, they aren't directly available in a Leads List View. To view the data of all converted Leads you will need to either use a standard Lead report or create a Custom Report Type based on your Organization's needs. Learn how to accomplish this below.

Create a Report to View Converted Leads

1. Click the Reports Tab.
2. Click New Report.
3. Click on (+) sign next to the Leads folder, and select the report type "Leads With Converted Lead Information."
4. Click Create.
   If the default fields do not show you the desired information, you can select additional fields from the section on the left by dragging and dropping them onto the Preview section.
5. Click the "Add" drop down next to Filters and select "Field Filter."
6. Set your criteria to "Converted equals True."
7. Click Run Report.

Source : https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=How-to-view-Converted-Leads-in-your-Organization&language=en_US

Comment: This is a good point, in the comments I was working under the assumption OP converted the lead as a System Administrator and then tried to view it as a Test User.

Comment: @DanJones what does it mean by "OP converted the lead" ? :)

Comment: Original Poster or the Asker.

Comment: Ok thanks @prabhat. In addition to that , i am having a side bar(custom console component) which contains a vf page. After converting the lead , i am getting "The data you were trying to access could not be found. It may be due to another user deleting the data or a system error. If you know the data is not deleted but cannot access it" . How can i overcome this ? I mean after converting , i should not see this error message

Comment: @hiSFDC You may check your VF page make changes in your error message.

Comment: Cant get you prabhat !!!

Comment: @hiSFDC You must have a Visual force page for the error. You need to check that.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be set at the Profile level, via [Profile Name] -> Administrative Permissions -> View and Edit Converted Leads